# Is there an ESLint rule to restrict using hardcoded color values in styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, styled-components

It would be great if you could help me with the following issue I have!

In our project, I would like to enforce that our developers only use the already provided colors.

Is there a way to check if hardcoded strings such as `#FFFFFF`, `rgb(255,255,255)`, `rgba(255,255,255,0.5)`, `red`, `white`, etc.., are used in styled-components in React using ESLint?

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { colors } from 'custom';

// Fail 
const Container1 = styled.div`
  ...
  color: red;
  ...
`;


// Fail
const Container2 = styled.div`
  ...
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  ...
`;


// Pass
const Container2 = styled.div`
  ...
  color: ${colors.red};
  ...
`;
```

I got it to work for for the following cases below using this `no-restricted-syntax` ESLint rule, but not for the template literals in the `styled-components`

```
"no-restricted-syntax": [
      "error",
      { "selector": "Literal[value=/^#[a-zA-Z0-9]/i]", "message": "Use 'colors.X' from 'custom'" },
      { "selector": "Literal[value=/^rgb[(]/i]", "message": "Use 'colors.X' from 'custom'" },
      { "selector": "Literal[value=/^rgba[(]/i]", "message": "Use 'colors.X' from 'custom'" }
    ]
```

```
// Got this to fail
const color1 = '#FFFFFF';
const color2 = 'rgb(255,255,255);
const color3 = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

// Got this to pass
const color4 = colors.white;
```

Comment: I got a bit unsure just now after answering your question - whether I understod it correctly. If I didn't, can you please provide the code snippet where you expect it to work - but doesn't?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use selector of "no-restricted-syntax properly to make ESLint behave like this:


``` lang-js
// ESlint should throw an error here 
const Container1 = styled.div`
  ...
  color: red;
  ...
`;

// ESlint should throw an error here 
const Container2 = styled.div`
  ...
  background-color: $FFFFFF;
  ...
`;

// ESlint should throw an error here 
const Container2 = styled.div`
  ...
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  ...
`;

// ESlint should consider this as correct
const Container2 = styled.div`
  ...
  color: ${colors.red};
  ...
`;
```

Comment: You can try this plugin https://github.com/gmullerb/eslint-plugin-regex and define text based regex with `regex/invalid`

Answer (score 0):

Add an eslint exception of `no-restricted-syntax` around the color definitions to disable the rule for that particular section in styled-components:

```js
/* eslint no-restricted-syntax: 0 */

// ... colors

/* eslint no-restricted-syntax: 1 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your `no-restricted-syntax` rule to do validation over `TemplateElement[value.raw=`. E.g. here is example of restricting `px` usage in template strings

```json
          {
            "selector": "TemplateElement[value.raw=/:\\s+\\d+px/i]",
            "message": "Absolute length units are not responsive.\nUse Relative length units.\nSee: \nhttps://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.php\n"
          }
```

Another option - using this plugin https://github.com/gmullerb/eslint-plugin-regex where you can define regex on `regex/invalid` rule. This way, linter will match against raw code.